# Django UpdateView without pk in the url

Tags: python, django, security, url

I am using Django's UpdateView to update a user's profile.
I pass the pk of the profile in the url like the following:

```
url(r'^profile/edit/(?P<pk>(\d+))$', profileviews.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
```

and in the view.py, I just use the UpdateView:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
```

It can work.
However, I find that if I login as ANOTHER user and type in the same url, I will be able to edit this user's profile! 
This is definitely wrong and by no means should another user have access to editing others' profile.

May I know if there are very good solutions to solve this problem? Hiding pk in url? Or other better solutions?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### URLs

```
# ... omitted
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', profileviews.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
# ... omitted
```

#### Views

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = UserProfileForm

    def get_object(self):
        """
        Returns the request's user.
        """
        return self.request.user.get_profile()

    # Then (unrelated, but for security)
    dispatch = login_required(UpdateView.dispatch)
```

Comment: Hi, orokusaki. Thank you. May I know if the get_object(self) will return the user? but actually I need the user profile. can we get the user profile pk instead?

Comment: @Wei Xu pardon, yep I've updated the answer with that.

Comment: Thanks. I think I should have read through the documentation before asking. The answer is actually quite clear. Thank you!

Comment: @WeiXu no prob, you're welocome

Comment: I get the error: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_profile'. I use Django 1.11.
Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @J.Hesters Django removed that method a couple versions back - the new way of doing this is to use a `OneToOneField` from your `Profile` model to the `User` model, and then simply use `user.profile` to get the `Profile`, or `hasattr(user, ‘profile’)` to check if the `User` has a `Profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need to pass the user PK in at all? Just have the url be

```
url(r'^profile/edit/', login_required(profileviews.ProfileUpdateView.as_view()), name=profile)
```

and use `self.request.user` in the view to get the correct initial information. That way it will always show the info of the logged in user.

Edited to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Override dispatch and check if the profile being edited belongs to the currently logged in user, this can conveniently be located in a mixin for easy reuse.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right. Could you give an example of code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
```

to decorate your `dispatch` function in your `CBV` as shown in the django doc's:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: Thank you. login_required help to guarantee that the user has loved in but cannot guarantee that the user will only be able to edit his own profile. If he type in the url, e.g., profile/edit/6, he might be able to edit others profile.

Comment: That is a good point. So keeping the pk out of the URL is better than so it doesn't allow for accessing others' profiles.

Comment: Or try adding @login_required